# SharePoint 2010 version history limit

Tags: versioning, limitations, boundaries

I was reading about SharePoint 2010 list and library version history boundaries and found, that the limit is 400'000 (source [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx) from Technet). 
But I got a bit confused - does this limit refers to one item or to all items combined in list/library?

And other question - if limit is exceeded, what will happen? In article there is said that "basic operations may not succeed", but what it realy means? What "plays the major role" of *succeeding* or *not succeeding* - WFE and SQL server *horsepower*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is for all items combined in list and library.

If you exceed this limit, basic file operations—such as file open or save, delete, and viewing the version history— may not succeed.

Please follow this link to get more idea how it effects your sharepoint

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc262813.aspx

Comment: For example, if I already have about 500k items in one library and I turn on versioning (for each item SharePoint creates first version), so probability of malfunction instantly rises?

Comment: No When versioning is enabled, versions are created in the following situations:

1. When a list item or file is first created or when a file is uploaded.



2.When a file is uploaded that has the same name as an existing file and the Add as a new version to existing files check box is selected.

3.When the properties of a list item or file are changed.

4.When a file is opened, edited, and saved. A version is created when you first click Save. 

5.When, during co-authoring of a document, a different user begins working on the document.